# Make DIV float to the bottom instead on top

Tags: css

I have two DIV's, first one is auto width (the content), second one is fixed width.

When the screen gets too narrow/window scaled, the fixed width DIV goes on the top and becomes 100% width as well. I would like to replicate this, but **I want the fixed DIV to go on the bottom, not top, when browser gets too narrow**. How can I accomplish this? Thanks.

(Please check in 'Full-Page' mode)

```css
.container-wrapper
{
    overflow:   hidden;    
}

.fixed-right
{
   overflow:     hidden;
   min-height:   100px;
   min-width:    400px;
   float:        right;
}

.auto-left
{
   overflow:     hidden;
   min-height:   100px;
}

.fancy
{
   border-radius: 2px;
   background-color:lightgray;
   margin-left: 5px;
   padding: 5px;
}

  @media 
  only screen and (max-width: 764px), (min-device-width: 764px) and (max-device-width: 1024px)  
  {
       .fixed-right
       {
          float:          none;
          width:          auto;
          margin-left:    0px;
          margin-bottom:  5px;
        }
  }
```

```html
<div class="container-wrapper">
  <div class='fixed-right fancy'>
   Fixed&nbsp;
  </div>

  <div class="auto-left fancy">
   Auto&nbsp;
  </div>
 </div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try adding this into your @media-query;

```
.container-wrapper {
  display: flex; 
  flex-direction: column-reverse;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `display: flex;` on your wrapper. Switch the `flex-direction` in the two different viewports.  Note this solution becomes more flexible if you add more elements to the wrapper, being able to set the order.

Then define the order of the divs.

- in the large view you set the right div to order 1
- in smaller you set it to 0, that means it will be first (on top)

```css
.container-wrapper {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
}

.fixed-right {
  overflow: hidden;
  min-height: 100px;
  min-width: 400px;
  order: 1;
}

.auto-left {
  overflow: hidden;
  min-height: 100px;
}

.fancy {
  border-radius: 2px;
  background-color: lightgray;
  margin-left: 5px;
  padding: 5px;
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 764px),
(min-device-width: 764px) and (max-device-width: 1024px) {
  .container-wrapper {
    flex-direction: column;
  }
  
  .fixed-right {
    width: auto;
    margin-left: 0px;
    margin-bottom: 5px;
    order: 0;
  }
  
  .fancy {
    margin-left: 0;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="container-wrapper">
  <div class='fixed-right fancy'>
    Fixed&nbsp;
  </div>

  <div class="auto-left fancy">
    Auto&nbsp;
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Pretty easy, change the order of the Divs in the HTML DOM:

```
    <div class="container-wrapper">
        <div class="auto-left fancy">
            Auto&nbsp;
        </div>
    <div class='fixed-right fancy'>
            Fixed&nbsp;
    </div>  
    </div>
```

The float right, will make it as you wanted on desktop